# Client-side solution similar to asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I recently started using WebStorm to implement web applications and find the experience much better than using Visual Studio.

I am considering moving the "view" part in mvc to pure html as much as possible without relying on server template engine such as Razor. So that I don't have to open visual studio until server side code is needed.

Google results showed that client side template engines such as Handlebars and Mustache will be able to help generate dynamic html pages. One thing I have not found is that ability to combine "parts" of pages together (like the master page in asp.net) so that we don't need to copy/paste header/footer everywhere.

How do I achieve "master page"-like functionality with client side (i.e. javascript) solutions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
use 'shtml' file to struct your webpage,so that you can reference the include instruction:

```
<!--#include file="head.html"--><hr><b>Hello,this is body!</b><hr><!--#include file="foot.html"-->
```

As to 'head.html' and 'foot.html',well,you know what should include in them.Actually,they are 'div' segments~~~